# Regular polygons inscribed in an ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

A regular $n$-gon is inscribed in an ellipse which is not a circle. what are the possible values for $n$? I know I can inscribe a square or even a equilateral triangle, but can we do it for all $n$? I think the answer is negative, but how to prove it?

Answer (score 4):

A conic is fixed by five points in general position. Since the only conic through five (or more) concyclic points is a circle, the only regular $n$-agons that can be inscribed in a ellipse are a triangle or a square.

Comment: Why is it the only conic with those properties?

Comment: @user226058: because two conics through the same set of five points in general position are the same conic.

Answer (score 0):

Five coplanar points (not in a line) determine a conic curve. Thus, for $n\ge 5$ the only conic is the circumscribed circle.